# Dynamically create instances from defined class

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make some kind of simulation/game in which I want to create planets by clicking which follow gravitation. I do this to learn about classes and Pygame.

I have a class

```py
class planet:
    
    planets=[]
    
    position     = np.array([100, 100], dtype=float)
    velocity     = np.array([  0,   0], dtype=float)
    acceleration = np.array([  0,   0], dtype=float)
    mass         = 10.
    
    def __init__(self,
                 position     = np.array([100, 100],dtype=float),
                 velocity     = np.array([  0,   0], dtype=float),
                 acceleration = np.array([  0,   0], dtype=float),
                 mass         = 10.):
        
        self.__class__.planets.append(self)
        self.position = position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.mass     = mass
```

and I am trying to create the planets using events from Pygame, using the mouse position as planet position/velocity

```py
while True:
    screen.blit(hintergrund, (0,0))
    
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: #get planet position
            mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: #get planet direction and create planet
            mx2, my2 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

I know how to create a single planet, or use pre-created ones, but is it possible to create them dynamically with a generated name?

Comment: What do you mean *"but is it possible to create them dynamically with a **generated name**"*? You do not need to generate a variable for a planet. The "name". You can access the planes by subscription: `planet.planets[i]` where `ì` is the index of the planet in the list.

Answer (score 1):

one option is to append class object to a list and access it by index like this

```
list_[index]  # index is an integer
```

the other option is appending them to a dictionary which would allow access by name like this:

```
planets = dict()
for i in range(your_range):
    planets[f'planet_nr_{i}'] = Planet()
```

this way you can access each class by variable name like this:

```
planet = planets['planet_nr_2']
```